# Amazon web services

Tags: ssh, windows-8.1, remote-desktop, amazon-web-services

I am trying to establish remote desktop connection to my Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance from Windows 8.1(local system), followed all of the following steps mentioned in [amazon aws docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-to-linux-desktop-from-windows/)

At 16th step it says

> On Windows, open the Remote Desktop Connection client, paste the fully
>   qualified name of your Amazon EC2 instance for the Computer, and then
>   click Connect

When ever I try this step I am getting error as `remote access to the connection are not enabled` , `remote computer is turned off`, `remote computer is not available on the network`

tried connecting through public DNS, path to pem key in my local system, and Instance ID too.

I am new to working with aws!

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: When I trying to connect with public ip address it says " remote access to the connection are not enabled" , "remote computer is turned off", "remote computer is not available on the network".

Comment: This is information that should be in your question. Are you sure the xrdp service is running, and that the changes that should be in your xrdp.ini file is correct?

Comment: Are you able to telnet to that instance? Check whether port is open to the instance?

Comment: I got the answer, Thanks for your help. I gave username "ubuntu" and used ec2 instance public ip address to connect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't Connect To AWS EC2 Instance via Putty](https://superuser.com/questions/853506/cant-connect-to-aws-ec2-instance-via-putty)