# SSH Using Putty into Amazon EMR

Tags: ssh, putty, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to follow the instructions to SSH into Amazon EMR:

```
Download PuTTY.exe to your computer from:
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html
Start PuTTY.
In the Category list, click Session.
In the Host Name field, type hadoop@ec2-54-242-105-186.compute-1.amazonaws.com
In the Category list, expand Connection > SSH, and then click Auth.
For Private key file for authentication, click Browse and select the private key file (sps_ml.ppk) used to launch the cluster.
Click Open.
Click Yes to dismiss the security alert.
```

But I'm receiving an error every time:

```
Network error: Connection timed out
```

I've already opened port 22 in Windows Firewall (added an inbound and outbound rule).  I've also setup port forwarding on my router for port 22 TCP.

I've also checked my setup at http://www.portchecktool.com./ and it tells me that my ISP/Router/Firewall is not blocking port 22.

What else could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to add my own IP address to the security group associated with the instance.  The answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/853506/cant-connect-to-aws-ec2-instance-via-putty?rq=1) helped lead me to the solution.

Comment: Please accept your answer, otherwise people will still look at this question thinking it hasn't been answered yet.

Comment: @yamakaja you can't accept your own answer to a question until after 48 hours

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry then